# Why do I need to typecast Viewstate Variables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in asp.net and I have encountered these following statements

Statement 1

```
ViewState["clicks"] = 5;
```

Statement 2

```
ViewState["clicks"] = (int)ViewState["clicks"] + 1;
```

My doubt is If I am able to directly assign int value...Why do I need to typecast when I am incrementing the value in viewstate variable?
Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Because the ViewState indexer returns an `object` type, and you cannot implicitly do `object + int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewState["clicks"]` returns an `object`. You can't use the [`+`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx)(addition) on `Object`. Therefore you need to cast the object to it's real type `int`. Then it compiles.

The right side is evaluated first and assigned back to the `ViewState`. Maybe it's getting clearer if you make it multiple lines:

```
int oldClicks = (int)ViewState["clicks"];
int newClicks = oldClicks + 1;
ViewState["clicks"] = newClicks;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `ViewState[]` will return object of type `object`.